# Autofac IContainer and DiagnosticTracer for ASP .Net 5

Tags: autofac, asp.net5

How I can get `IContainer` instance for my ASP.Net 5 app?
I need to enable diagnostics, and based on [official documentation](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/debugging.html) `SubscribeToDiagnostics` method is accessible only from `IContainer`, and [ASP Net Core 3+ Integration](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#asp-net-core-3-0-and-generic-hosting) `this.AutofacContainer = app.ApplicationServices.GetAutofacRoot();` exposes only `ILifetimeScope`.

I have also noticed that Autofac supports `DiagnosticListener` - is this a way how I should trace for informations?

Does Autofac provide build in formatters for example for `RequestDiagnosticData`?

What are your recommendations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've updated the [ASP.NET Core 3 example for Autofac](https://github.com/autofac/Examples/blob/691e302ef8fe73bdbceb39445607bfb3b1500b31/src/AspNetCore3Example/Startup.cs#L35) to show how this works. The secret is using a build callback.

In your `ConfigureContainer` method, you register a callback to subscribe to diagnostics.

```cs
public void ConfigureContainer(ContainerBuilder builder)
{
    // Add any Autofac modules or registrations, then...
    //
    // If you want to enable diagnostics, you can do that via a build
    // callback. Diagnostics aren't free, so you shouldn't just do this
    // by default. Note: since you're diagnosing the container you can't
    // ALSO resolve the logger to which the diagnostics get written, so
    // writing directly to the log destination is the way to go.
    var tracer = new DefaultDiagnosticTracer();
    tracer.OperationCompleted += (sender, args) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(args.TraceContent);
    };

    builder.RegisterBuildCallback(c =>
    {
        var container = c as IContainer;
        container.SubscribeToDiagnostics(tracer);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, are there any performance differences between DiagnosticTracer vs subscribing to DiagnosticListener? From documentation I know that DiagnosticTracer cannot be disabled if enabled, however DiagnosticTracer can be unsubscribed.

Comment: There is non-zero perf overhead door any diagnostics to which you subscribe. There are optimized paths in Autofac to speed things up when there are no diagnostics subscribers.